# Do I need to call 'Remove-Job' in PowerShell?

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I inherited some scripts from another software engineer, and these scripts use Start-Job to start doing many things at once.  These jobs output to the filesystem, so it's not necessary to receive them in order to use them, simply to wait until they've finished.  So, to clarify...

- Start-Job is called
- Wait-Job is called
- Stop-Job is called
- Receive-Job is NOT called
- Remove-Job is NOT called
- The script that created these jobs terminates normally in about 10 minutes

My understanding is that either receiving or removing a job will delete it, and we do neither of those.

My question for you is: Do I have a memory leak?  Is calling Remove-Job (or Receive-Job) necessary if the thread that created the job terminates normally?

Comment: it's _always_ a good idea to remove large chunks of RAM-using code once the code is done. [*grin*] that said, however, if your script entirely exits ... then the jobs should also be cleaned up. ///// i would explicitly do a `Remove-Job` in your situation, tho. i prefer to avoid depending on default behavior when there is a neat, clean way to explicitly clean up after myself.

Comment: Thanks @Lee_Dailey.  I'm explicitly cleaning up the jobs now, but we're looking into whether past problems with the scripts hanging could have been caused by this.  (I'm not asking for assistance on that; don't worry.)

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to kinda-sorta help ... and good luck with your project! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are not scheduled jobs, they are terminated when the shell is closed. So if your script runs, then exits, the jobs are removed.

Like @Lee_Dailey said, explicit cleanup is always a good idea.

If this was your script, the job is terminated almost instantly.

```
start-job -scriptblock { dir c:\windows -recurse }
exit
```

Comment: It is not a PowerShell scheduled job, but I did take a quick read on those.  I have added explicit cleanup to the scripts for the future.  We're looking into whether we might have had problems in the past because of this, and it's feeling like a "probably not" because the jobs should be cleaned up when Powershell exits.  Thanks Mike!

Comment: Well, I created a PS Script to test this, and if I run the script multiple times, Get-Job still returns old jobs. If I have a different Powershell window (shell) open or I close and re-open the window, then the jobs don't appear in the Get-Job output anymore. Looks like this could have been a problem in repeated testing, but not in production (where we use a Scheduled Task, so it runs with a fresh shell every time). Thanks again.